# How is the order of suggested edits in the review queue handled?

Tags: bug, review-queues, edits, suggested-edits

So I just went through my rejected edits and found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12240163).

Well, obviously this can not be considered a good edit compared to the formatting of the question show on the left and therefore the reasons for the rejection are also quite fitting.

**However**, I was pretty sure that I never made such an edit (which clearly makes the formatting worse than before). So I went ahead and looked at the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37025124/revisions) of that question. As we can see, my edit was obviously aimed at the first version of the question (for which it did fix the original formatting). It was not meant to be an edit to the edit by @CarbineCoder as one could think from only looking at the review queue entry.

Now my question is: How does the review queue handle the order of suggested reviews?

Normally from my experience, if I suggest an edit and someone else comes in - in the meantime of it getting approved/rejected - and directly edits the post, then my edit is usually (and rightfully so) rejected with the reason 
`This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit.`
Shouldn't this have also happened in this case instead of suggesting that I edited someone else's edit whereas I didn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Carbine's edit was at ... **May 4 at 10:31:38**
- Your edit was at ........... **May 4 at 10:31:57**

I highly suspect that this was some sort of race condition. If you would have waited a tiny bit longer, it would have told you another edit was made already.

This isn't your fault. It's just a risk of editing new questions.

We should ideally find a way to fix the system so this doesn't happen in the future.

Comment: [But... but... the alignment!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qfebq.png)