# When exactly does the edit link on a question get disabled?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

Today I was about to edit a poorly-described question, and I noticed the edit link was disabled.

When exactly does the link get disabled and enabled again? I mean, for example:

- from when someone clicks `edit` to he/she closes-edit-dialogue/submits-changes?
- from when the edit evaluation starts by moderators to its approval/rejection?

Comment: When there's a pending edit you can't make any more edits before the first one is approved/rejected. I'm guessing this was the case here.

Comment: So you mean 2 guys can start to edit same post simultaneously? And edit button only gets disabled some edit is in approval/rejection queue , and not when someone just starts(clicks the edit link somewhere else) to edit?

Comment: Exactly. You can start editing a question but if someone else submits their edit before you, you won't be able to submit yours. Very rarely the system is too slow to catch up with the fact that someone else has already edited the question and then things like [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324018/6214222) might happen.

Comment: I think higher rep can override others. Sometimes I'll comment with `[edit]` just so I can get the link, then I'll edit myself.

Comment: @cricket_007, If editing is disabled due to a pending edit which you have already reviewed, you can force-edit the current question with this bookmarklet: `javascript:void(window.open(location.href.replace('questions','posts').replace(/([0-9]{4}[0-9]*)\/.*/,'$1/edit')))`. The bookmarklet effectively strips the URL down to minimal and adds `/edit`. Doing this acts as if you had clicked "Improve Edit" in the Suggested Edits review queue. In other words, the pending edit is approved and you edit that version. The bookmarklet could be changed to edit answers too, should you desire.

Comment: @Keiwan Except when you can review suggested edits, and have not reviewed the pending suggested edit yet. In that scenario, you can click the edit link and open up a review modal window to approve, reject, or edit the pending edit. Once you've voted and the window closes, the edit link will be greyed out unless you cast the final approval or rejection vote, or unless you chose to edit & approve while reviewing (in which case the pending edit and your edit would be applied, in respective order).

Comment: @TylerH Yes, I know about that, but that's still the same as what I've written in my comments. The pending edit still has to be approved/rejected before another edit is applied. It's just that if you're over 2000 rep you can help with this process yourself.

Comment: @Makyen are you sure? I've done that in the past and it has always rejected the edit. Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15370151)

Comment: @TinyGiant, You are correct. I stand corrected. You edit the changed version (as if you clicked "Improve Edit"), but the pending edit is [rejected as an edit conflict](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14870214), which does not report the same as ["Reject and Edit"](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14779907).

Comment: @Keiwan, You can force the edit (see above), without first explicitly approving or rejecting the pending edit. If you save, the pending edit is rejected as an edit conflict, as pointed out by Tiny Giant. I have not tested if this is possible with <2K rep.

Comment: @Makyen Are you talking about the situation when someone submits their edit while you're also editing and your editing dialog is open? So you can save without even noticing that there was another edit?

Comment: @Keiwan, No, I am saying that you can choose to manually, or using non-stock links (see bookmarklet above), start a new edit while there is a pending edit by navigating to the edit page for the question/post. You can then submit that edit without having reviewed the pending edit.

Comment: @Keiwan, You can also do this by navigating to the revisions page for the post and selecting to edit a specific version of the post using the stock links that are provided on that page. If there is only one revision of the answer/question, you would need to manually navigate to the revisions page for that post. For example, this question's [revisions page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/344599/revisions).

Comment: @Makyen Good, I also originally understood your comment this way. I'm just a little confused since I never said any of your explanations are wrong or that there is no way for someone with over 2k rep to "force" an edit while there is one pending. Whether it's by clicking "Improve edit", "Reject and Edit", using the bookmarklet or via the revisions page, the pending edit gets (either directly or indirectly) approved or rejected and then the new edit is applied. That was the point I was trying to make :)

Comment: @Keiwan, I read your comments as indicating that the pending edit *must* complete the review process prior to it being *possible* to submit a new edit. While the main "edit" link will not result in being able to edit the post, it is possible to submit an edit prior to the pending edit completing the review process. Submitting the new edit immediately ends the review process with the prior pending edit being rejected as an edit conflict. I have not tested to see if this is possible for users with <2K rep. Perhaps we are just miscommunicating due to semantics.

Comment: @Makyen Miscommunication it is. When I wrote *"won't be able to submit yours"* in my second comment I was specifically referring to the situation when two people have edited the question at the same time but one submitted theirs first. The second person won't be able to just save their edit as if nothing happened. In the end we are really just saying the same thing (or at least agreeing on everything).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Quoting [the FAQ on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81701/167646):

> There are a handful of conditions where we will stop accepting
>   suggested edits:
>
> 1. A large number of suggested edits by you were rejected in the past week (at least [5 more than one-third of your accepted
>      edits](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91392/too-many-of-your-edits-were-rejected-try-again-in-7-days/92337#92337)).
> 2. We are out of empty slots in the queue (*200 on Stack Overflow*. See
>      [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84362/whats-the-fixed-size-of-the-suggested-edit-queue/84398#84398)
>      for details)
> 3. You have 5 suggested edits pending.
> 4. There is an edit to a particular post that was not approved yet.
> 5. You are not logged in and the post is less than 10 minutes old.
> 6. You are on a child meta.
> 7. Your account is suspended.
> 8. The post is locked.
>
> In the past no "edit" link would be shown at all; since July 2012 the
>   edit link [is
>   disabled](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91172/always-show-the-edit-button-on-questions/138944#138944)
>   and the mouse hover tooltip will explain why an edit cannot be
>   suggested, like "Account is not allowed to suggest edits".

Comment: I also found the edit button to be disabled when I had too many outstanding pending edits. I think it was 5 that I had so until one of them was reviewed I couldn't edit anymore. Not sure if that's user specific.

Comment: @Bugs that could be reason 2 in the list, but if anyone else can confirm that, we can add it to the list.

Comment: I have just managed to replicate. I had 5 pending edits and wasn't allowed to do any more. There is a hover over message that also advises this so it's not ambiguous.

Comment: @Bugs I found http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work which confirms what you're seeing, looks like the two answers are out of sync. Thank you for the remark! I'll do some edits to the posts.

Comment: @Stijn: no, #2 is a different limit. There is a global (per site) cap, and a *per user cap*. The latter is relatively new, see [Rate limit suggested edits](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/210416)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Right, I forgot about that one. I had even upvoted the request :)